# SQLite db access with java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite

I need to access a SQLite database with java. i get this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

whenever i want to create my sessionFactory bean.

database properties:

```
db.driver.class=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.server.url=jdbc:sqlite:"G:\\Ausbildung\\username\\Database\\informations.db"
db.username=
db.password=

db.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
db.hibernate.schema=DATA
db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

bean declaration in xml file:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${db.driver.class}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${db.server.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${db.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${db.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.mainfirst.bloomberg.invoice.report.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${db.hibernate.schema}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I can't find the mistake i made. this construct worked with Apache Derby. I only changed the hibernate.dialect and the driver.class as well as server.url.

if i remove the "" in the db.server.url i get the error

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.sqlite.Conn.isValid(I)Z

Thanks in advance

Comment: fixed the java.lang.AbstractMethodError by taking newer version of jdbc driver. now only the dialect error exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the problem with taking this SQLite dialect for hibernate:

```
<groupId>com.enigmabridge</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate4-sqlite-dialect </artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
```